# What are some good converters to rip audio from YouTube videos?

Tags: webapp-rec, youtube, video, audio, mp3

I have some videos that I want to listen to, but don't really want to watch. What are some good sites to download just the audio in formats like MP3?

Answer (score 1):

Check [ListenToYouTube.com](http://www.listentoyoutube.com/) also.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.zamzar.com but I preffer http://savevideo.me now.

The difference is that Zamzar sends the download link to your email after the processing and conversion to the audio format.

SaveVideoMe rips the video from Youtube that you can download directly (including FLV, MP4 and HD if available) and then you can convert them with other tool like the excellent Mobile media converter mentioned here. This way the video and audio quality are preserved since there's no conversion involved.